# create a new visualization calendar with filter by membership

Tags: filter

A need show events on calendar using filter membership using camlQuery.
Can i replace the ListViewXml on the aspx? i use javascript on the sharepoint designer.

Comment: I have a list with some groups, ex: group 1, and i need to show the events only current user is on that group

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? Are you using modern or classic SharePoint?